# Showing all the products except the current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to see all the products in the products table except those products which belongs to the current_user:

products_controller.rb

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
    resources :products
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.where('user_id<>?',current_user.id)
```